# Creating offline multiplayer Android games with Unity

Tags: android, unity, multiplayer

Is it possible to create offline multiplayer Android games with Unity (played over bluetooth/ wi-fi)?
If so, then I would like to create a 2 player game prototype, containing a single room (empty cube) with 2 cubes (3rd person controllers) - each controlled by one player. The cubes can be moved about as their owners (players) wish. Any movement made by any of the 2 players can be seen in realtime in the other player's display.
How do I achieve this?

P.S. I know some basics of Unity. I have already created a small hack & slash game in Unity (PC-standalone). I am new to Unity Android, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to create offline multi-player games with Unity3D. You can achieve this most easily by using Unity's built in Master Server.

[Unity3D Master Server](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/net-MasterServer.html)

A good tutorial for learning how to use Unity's built in networking can be found here:
[M2H Networking Tutorial](http://www.scribd.com/doc/38400039/M2H-Unity-Networking-Tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

If you go into Appstore, you can download the "Unity remote tester~", connect via bluetooth and play test it on your device :)

As for the tutorials, as @Xerosigma noted, the M2H NetworkTutorial is great, but you would like to learn how unity reacts with the mobile systems. For instance the standard terrain will not work on a IOS/Android, and so on.

If I am to recommend anything. Just read about creating any Mobile MMO/Multiplayer game.
Here is a starter kit for a shooter.

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/166531-Announce-Mobile-MMO-FPS-Multiplayer-Kit